# Combining grammar-translation method and direct method to teach English

Tags: teaching-methods

Should we use two or three methods at the same time to teach English? For example: Grammar translation method, Direct method, etc. More specifically, **is it acceptable to combine the grammar-translation method and a direct method for teaching English**?

Comment: "Should" sounds too subjective. Can you [edit] the question to clarify what benefits are you trying to get?

Comment: Do you want to know whether it is recommended to combine specific methods (e.g. according to research)? Should the answers covers specific methods that you have in mind? Just for English, or for a specific type of language, or for a specific family of languages?

Comment: @bytebuster I think "should" is just fine (if not, feel free to edit); recommendations can still be based on scientific studies, research, etc. I think we should be careful to not be *too* picky about what questions are tolerated.

Comment: @thein lwin, if you are still registered on Stack Exchange, please clarify your question. It cannot be answered in its current state and is at risk of getting closed if it does not get improved.